# How do I get one field from a SQL fetch in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm initiating this userName field...

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state ={ isLoading: true}
    this.state = {userName: null}
  }
```

to be fetched from a "SELECT" that retrieves just one row from a table...

```
  componentDidMount(){
    return fetch('http://creat1vedesign.com/user.php')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          userName: responseJson.userName,
        }, function(){

        });

      })
      .catch((error) =>{
        console.error(error);
      });
  }
```

retrieved row is...

```
[{"userName":"carolf","name":"Carol Faria","picture":"https:\/\/scontent.fcgh4-1.fna.fbcdn.net\/v\/t1.0-9\/40643115_10209672379005555_7946763802064715776_n.jpg?_nc_cat=104&_nc_ht=scontent.fcgh4-1.fna&oh=ed8b3219863e6704326e429bd2899e9f&oe=5C7BE0F1","hasTab":"true"}]
```

and then used here...

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: '#F3A024', alignItems: 'center', height: 380 }}>
          <Text style={styles.textBorder}>{this.state.userName}</Text>
```

But userName is not updated with the fetched data (it remains null). What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive an array from the backend. So you must not set `responseJson.userName` but `responseJson[0].userName`.

It would be better ofcourse to return an object instead of an array in your PHP-script.